# Apache Authorization for multiple pages for different users

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, authorization

I have a website that I has common pages as well as restricted pages. I would like to restrict each page for each user, such that my cong

> /var/www/application/user1/user1.html
>
> /var/www/application/user2/user2.html .... for n users.

What kind of authorization module would be suitable? The filesystem permissions are set right. Eg. user2 dir is only accessible by user2.

I did put some effort to make it work for 1 user by specifying required user directive. But that doesn't scale well. I am new to apache confid.

Comment: Are you wanting to restrict editing the files or viewing the files through a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make use of Apache's htpasswd: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html

This guide from Apache will step you through editing the .htaccess file and adding user/password access to the various web pages: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html